# What is the reason why OneToOne relationship in Doctrine cannot be lazy loaded?

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I have a `Person` and `Admin` entity. One `Person` can only have one `Admin`, but I do not need admin all the time. When I list all people with admin associated, doctrine will load all admins from DB. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

In a case of one-to-one association (and in similar cases, e.g. while lazy loading one-to-many association) Doctrine generates so called [proxy objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/advanced-configuration.html#proxy-objects) for associated entities. These proxy objects mimics interface of target entity but only triggers actual data loading from database upon access to **non-id** field.

Because of this in your case when you're fetching list of `Person` entities - you doesn't get list of `Admin` entities fetched from database, but receiving list of `Admin` proxies instead. Unless you will (occasionally or intentionally) try to access some of properties of `Admin` entity (with exception of its `id` which can be safely accessed) Doctrine will not try to fetch any `Admin` information from database.

Consider following simplified setup of `A` and `B` entities with one-to-one association:

```
// A.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var B
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\B")
     */
    private $b;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return B
     */
    public function getB(): B
    {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

// B.php

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

You can proof that `A::$b` contain proxy object by either looking into debugger or by using reflection:

```
$entities = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(\App\Entity\A::class)->findAll();
/** @var \App\Entity\A $a */
$a = array_shift($entities);
$class = (new \ReflectionObject($a->getB()))->getName();
```

In this case value of `$class` variable will be `Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\B` (Doctrine proxy object for `App\Entity\B`) and not `App\Entity\B` as it would be in a case of normal entity object.

Comment: No my question is I am not accessing admin at all but it still got fetched

Comment: It is unlikely caused by Doctrine itself, it can be some part of your (or third-party) code that accesses proxied method, for example some kind of serializer or some reflection-based inspector. In this case I would recommend to set debugger breakpoint into proxy object for `Admin` entity and check where it was called from. Also looking into Doctrine SQL queries log may give you an idea how does information for these entities is being fetched.